# Losing References to Parent Classes

Tags: javascript, function, reference, typescript

I have two TypeScript classes; one of them has a method that returns a reference to a different method in an instance of the second class (Yes, a bit confusing). Here's the most watered-down example that still repros the problem (I included the compiled JS for people who would prefer that at the bottom):

```
class OuterClass {
    public InnerClassInstance: InnerClass;

    constructor() {
        this.InnerClassInstance = new InnerClass(7); //Create an instance of the inner class
                                                     //7 is just a test value
    }

    public DoStuff(): any { //Return a reference to the instance's method
        return this.InnerClassInstance.DoMoreStuff;
    }
}

class InnerClass {
    public VariableInstance: number; //Keep a variable (this is the main issue)

    constructor(Num: number) {
        this.VariableInstance = Num;
    }

    public DoMoreStuff() {
        alert(this.VariableInstance); //Demonstrate (hopefully) that everything worked
                                      //Displays 'undefined' instead
    }
}

var OuterClassInstance: OuterClass = new OuterClass();
OuterClassInstance.DoStuff()(); //Call DoMoreStuff from the instance in OuterClass
```

The problem is that once `DoMoreStuff` is called, it seems to have lost all connection with it's parent class. At that point, the instance `InnerClassInstance` is still right (the variable is 7), but `VariableInstance` when accessed directly from `DoMoreStuff` is undefined. This happens with all variables that are defined inside `InnerClass`.

Is there some sort of a spec that I've missed? I would think that the reference would keep it's context, but it seems that it looses that when it's called from the reference.

Here's the JS:

```
var OuterClass = (function () {
    function OuterClass() {
        this.InnerClassInstance = new InnerClass(7); //Create an instance of the inner class
                                                     //7 is just a test value
    }
    OuterClass.prototype.DoStuff = function () {
        return this.InnerClassInstance.DoMoreStuff;
    };
    return OuterClass;
})();

var InnerClass = (function () {
    function InnerClass(Num) {
        this.VariableInstance = Num;
    }
    InnerClass.prototype.DoMoreStuff = function () {
        alert(this.VariableInstance); //Demonstrate (hopefully) that everything worked
                                      //Displays 'undefined' instead
    };
    return InnerClass;
})();

var OuterClassInstance = new OuterClass();
OuterClassInstance.DoStuff()(); //Call DoMoreStuff from the instance in OuterClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `this` object is determined by the **method invocation pattern** being used. When a function is invoked as a function(`OuterClassInstance.DoStuff()();`) and not as a method(`object.method()`), this is bound to the `Global` object.

```
OuterClass.prototype.DoStuff = function () {
        return this.InnerClassInstance.DoMoreStuff;
};
```

`OuterClassInstance.DoStuff()()` is the same as:

```
var doStuff = OuterClassInstance.DoStuff();
doStuff();
```

Since there is no property named `VariableInstance` on the Global object, it results in `undefined`.

To work around this problem, return a function whose context is bound to the `InnerClass` instance using `Function.prototype.bind`

```
OuterClass.prototype.DoStuff = function () {
        return this.InnerClassInstance.DoMoreStuff.bind(this.InnerClassInstance);
};
```

Consider this example:

```
var o = {
  a: 'asdf',
  method: function () {
    return this.other;
  },
  other: function () {
    alert(this.a);
  }
};

o.method()(); //alerts undefined

method: function () {
    return this.other.bind(this);
}

o.method()(); //alerts asdf
```

Comment: Would not that rather be `return this.InnerClassInstance.DoMoreStuff.bind(this.InnerClassInstance)`?

Comment: Yup, Forgot `InnerClassInstance`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`DoMoreStuff` is called directly (i.e. not invoked as a method) so `this` takes the value of the `window` global object.

`DoMoreStuff` is trying to get `window.VariableInstance`, which is indeed undefined.

What you would need for this to work would be something like:

```
var InnerClass = (function () {
    var _this = this;                  // <--- closure for class instance
    function InnerClass(Num) {
        this.VariableInstance = Num;
    }
    InnerClass.prototype.DoMoreStuff = function () {
        alert(_this.VariableInstance); // <--- using class instance
    };
    return InnerClass;
}
```

After reading the other response, it appears bind() is the solution. Trouble is, it's only supported by ECMA5 browsers, so old IE versions won't have it.

A possible replacement for bind() would be :

```
function bind (proc, _this) {
    if (proc.prototype.bind) return proc.bind (_this);
    return function () { proc.call (_this); };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replacement implementation; decided to use bind as described above and then fall back to this

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to pass a function around you can use `arrow functions` :

```
public DoMoreStuff = () => { // you plan to pass this function around
    alert(this.VariableInstance); //Demonstrate (hopefully) that everything worked
                                  //Displays 'undefined' instead
}
```

So the complete code:

```
class OuterClass {
    public InnerClassInstance: InnerClass;

    constructor() {
        this.InnerClassInstance = new InnerClass(7); //Create an instance of the inner class
                                                     //7 is just a test value
    }

    public DoStuff(): any { //Return a reference to the instance's method
        return this.InnerClassInstance.DoMoreStuff;
    }
}

class InnerClass {
    public VariableInstance: number; //Keep a variable (this is the main issue)

    constructor(Num: number) {
        this.VariableInstance = Num;
    }

    public DoMoreStuff = () => { // you plan to pass this function around
        alert(this.VariableInstance); //Demonstrate (hopefully) that everything worked
                                      //Displays 'undefined' instead
    }
}

var OuterClassInstance: OuterClass = new OuterClass();
OuterClassInstance.DoStuff()(); //Call DoMoreStuff from the instance in OuterClass
```

The reason why it isn't the default is that it consumes more memory (as arrow members go on `this` and not `prototype`) and it isn't inheritance friendly (again same `this` vs. `prototype` logic).

Comment: Perfectly good answer, but I decided that the `bind` method would work better in my actual code